# Why was my answer deleted by a moderator for being a duplicate?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I am new to Stack Overflow and one of my answers was deleted by a moderator yesterday. The reason is that he thought I posted the same answer to multiple questions. I checked all my answers and did not find I posted that answer to any other questions by mistake. So I posted that answer again and then it was deleted by the same moderator again for the same reason. I know one answer is not a big deal but I want to know why so I wont' make same mistake in the future.

[Problem adding “pro mode” for Huawei Camera Kit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64636918)

Comment: Moderators get a system generated flag if you post the same answer to multiple questions.

Comment: If you go to `https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/14357441` do you see any other answers deleted apart from to that question?

Comment: Thanks, that same question got deleted twice.

Comment: you will see two entries for the same Q as you had two deleted answers on that Q as per Cody's answer. The issue seems to be that you originally got things muddled and posted the same answer text on the wrong question by mistake (and even though you fixed that mistake well before reposting it it was still auto flagged as a dupe).

Comment: Thanks Martin, I think that is the reason. What should I do if this kind of thing happened?

Comment: probably a custom flag on [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64615190/problem-adding-pro-mode-for-huawei-camera-kit/64636849#64636849) explaining why it should be undeleted would do it

Comment: That won't work. If I select "undeleted", a message will pop up saying: a moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted.

Comment: @Zinna You can't undelete it yourself, but you can flag it for a moderator to take another look (along with an explanation of why it shouldn't have been deleted).

Comment: Thanks, found the flag, sorry, still learning SOF. Will do

Answer (score 8):

You posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64616760/huawei-scene-kit-3d-model-does-not-display-after-loading-finishes/64624380#64624380) at 2020-10-31 17:06:37Z.

Then, you posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64615190/problem-adding-pro-mode-for-huawei-camera-kit/64636849#64636849) at 2020-11-01 20:49:09Z. This is the one that a moderator deleted with the following comment:

> Please [don't post identical answers to multiple questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question*.

This answer is identical to the previous one, which you posted on *a different question*, but was still an identical answer. As the moderator's comment suggested, if you can post the exact same answer to two different questions, then those questions are duplicates and you should flag them as such instead of posting identical answers. (Pick the best—in your opinion—question to answer, and then flag the other one as a duplicate of that best one.)

Later, at 2020-11-01 20:57:47Z, you posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64615190/problem-adding-pro-mode-for-huawei-camera-kit/64636918#64636918) to the same question where you already had an answer deleted. A moderator deleted it and left two comments:

- > Please [don't post identical answers to multiple questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question*.
- > Note: just reposting this while ignoring the feedback given is not really a good way to interact with the site and its community.

Comment: Right, so the first answer was totally edited at 2020-10-31 17:24:23 and probably posted on the wrong question

Comment: In which case it seems odd that they are being advised to "tailor your answers to the question" when the version detected as the original in the dupe pair was radically tailored more than 24 hour prior to the dupe detection

Comment: I sense some sort of "feature-request" here - it looks like what moderators see in that "duplicate" question does not reflect current state of the question... It is *very hard* to see how those two linked questions meet "duplicate, please provide answers matching questions" requirement... While this answer indeed explains what happened it really does not help OP (or anyone) what to do as everything OP could have done to remediate the problem was already done *before* the second "duplicate" post was made.

Comment: Yeah, this could be the reason. As I am still not familar with all the formatting in SOF, I usually use notepad to type and edit, then copy and paste them over. Could be one time I pasted the wrong one. That could explain why after a few days I found out there was one question I answered actually did not have my answer. I then posted the answer again and then got deleted. What if people made this type of mistake, what should we do? thanks

Comment: @Zinna This answer has been made a community wiki, so I'm not sure the poster gets your message here. When you flag your deleted Answer using "in need of moderator intervention", please be sure to give **all** the details, including your wrong copy'n'paste and your edits. Possibly also link to this meta post of yours.

Comment: I made this community wiki because the comments made me realize that perhaps I don't want to *endorse* all of the decisions that were made here. At the same time, I don't want to delete the answer, because it provides useful information and context to non-moderators. I simply don't have the time these days to dig into things any more thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks for all the helps here, I have already flagged my answer to the Moderator. Good learning process for me as well.

Comment: this issue appears to be resolved now

Comment: Thanks Martin, I saw it. For meta SOF question, do I need to accept one answer as the way in regular SOF?